# JEditable validate before sending ajax request

Tags: datatables, jeditable

How can you validate data before sending the data through an ajax request with JEditable? I would like the validation to prevent the ajax request if the edited data is not valid.

I would like to do something along the lines of...

```
dataTable.makeEditable (
{
 validateData: function() { return true/false; }
}
```